# Stop droid x from security locking during a call

Tags: security, motorola-droid-x, lock-screens

I have noticed that when I am on a lengthy call on my Droid X, the phone locks itself.  This seems to happen within the expected timeout period, so I don't believe that the phone is malfunctioning.  Instead, I just think that just bad design (if I am on the phone making a call, I would expect that to register as an activity and keep the handset from locking).

My question is whether there is any way to keep the phone from doing this (other than setting the timeout to off before I take a call).  I have Tasker on the phone, so I have been toying with the idea of setting up some workaround, but does anyone have any other options?

**UPDATE**: To be clear, I am talking about the phone locking (requiring you to re-enter security PIN or pattern to unlock) during a call, **not** the screen turning off when the phone is in proximity to your face.  So basically after a 20 minute phone call, if I want to check my mail, I need to enter my PIN.  I find this annoying and would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Why do you need the phone unlocked when you're on a call?  Sounds like a good way to end up hanging up via your ear :P

Comment: @Mathew I'm not talking about the screen lock (from the proximity sensor) but rather I mean the security pin lock.  After a long call, I have to re-enter my pin to unlock the phone - not user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Screebl](http://www.keyeslabs.com/joomla/screebl) can help - it enables/disables your phone's power saving features depending on the orientation (how the phone is held in your hand in relation to the ground).

Originally designed to keep the screen awake during a call, the PRO version also includes Tasker / Locale integration.